# I want to save list of subfolder in the csv file using a python script with 30 numbers but it is saved in scientific notation format

Tags: python, excel, csv

I want to save list of subfolder and password in the csv file using a python script with 30 numbers but it is saved in scientific notation format

```
enter code here
  import os
  import shutil
  import tarfile
  import pyzipper
  import csv
  import pandas as pd
  from random import choice
  
  def generatePassword(passlen, specialchar=True):
      if specialchar:
          password = ''.join([choice('ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789#&*@%$') for i in range(passlen)])
      else:
          password = ''.join([choice('ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789') for i in range(passlen)])
      return password
  
  current_dir = os.getcwd() # get the current directory
  target_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'target') # get the path to the target folder
  
  passwords = []
  for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(current_dir):
      if 'virt' in dirnames:
          dirnames.remove('virt') # exclude the folder from the search
      if 'target' in dirnames:
          dirnames.remove('target') # exclude the folder from the search    
      for dirname in dirnames:
          # create a compressed archive of the subfolder
          tar_name = f'{dirname}.zip'
          password = generatePassword(20)
          with pyzipper.AESZipFile(os.path.join(target_dir, tar_name), 'w', compression=pyzipper.ZIP_DEFLATED, encryption=pyzipper.WZ_AES) as zipfile:
              zipfile.setpassword(password.encode())
              for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)):
                  for file in files:
                      zipfile.write(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(os.path.relpath(root, os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)), file))
          passwords.append({'Folder': dirname, 'Password': password})
  
  # write the passwords to a CSV file with cell format of text
  df = pd.DataFrame(passwords)
  df['Folder'] = df['Folder'].astype(str)
  df.to_csv('passwords.csv', index=False, )
```

But I got this output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDEtb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change `astype(str)` to `astype(int)`. I assume your folder number is an integer. If not, then you can do the following:

```
df['Folder'] = df['Folder'].apply(lambda x: f"{x:.5f}")
```